# How to attach 2 views inorder for them to pan as one view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I want 2 views to act as if they were "one view" - meaning if view 1 moves on the 'x' n pixels I want view 2 to move on the x axis the same amount of pixels (in any arbitrary direction) - without having to calculate all sorts of offsets and so on.

I thought using the new `UIDynamicAnimator` would be a great candidate so I tried this

```
UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320-150, 150, 150, 100)];
v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:v1];

self.v1 = v1;
UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                                      0,
                                                      self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                      self.view.bounds.size.height)];
v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:v2];
self.v2 = v2;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *p = 
 [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
[v1 addGestureRecognizer:p];

self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

UIAttachmentBehavior *att = 
 [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.v1 
                           offsetFromCenter:UIOffsetZero 
                             attachedToItem:self.v2 
                           offsetFromCenter:UIOffsetMake(0, 
                                         self.v1.center.y - self.v2.center.y)];
att.damping = 0;
[self.animator addBehavior:att];
self.att = att;

-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        // move only on x axis but keep on same y point
        self.v1.center = CGPointMake(p.x, self.v1.center.y);
        [self.animator updateItemUsingCurrentState:self.v1];

    }
}
```

But they are interacting with each other - the little view tilts and changes its rotation and y location.

I would have hoped - only on 1 axis and "hard" connected to each other - any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Given that no further details about the context is provided, I assume that you want the two views' relative distance to each other to remain constant. If this is indeed the case, I am not sure why you consider `UIDynamicAnimator`. Instead, you could embed the two views in a containerview and then manipulate the origin of the container instead of the two views individually. By embracing this approach you don't have to worry about re-calculating the origin of one view when moving the other, and vice versa.

```
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100 0, 100, 100)];
[self.containerView addSubview:v1];
[self.containerView addSubview:v2];

// now, changing the origin of containerView will move v1 and v2 simultaniously
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        // move only on x axis but keep on same y point
        self.containerView.center = CGPointMake(p.x, self.containerView.center.y);
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could use autolayout and relate the two views in such way that your requirements are met. Then, when moving one of the views, the other will move accordingly. However, if you are actually using `UIDynamics` to manipulate views in that view hierarchy, autolayout is not the way to go since autolayout and `UIDynamics` tend to interfere with each other.

Comment: And don't forget to set pan gesture recognizer on superview and superview's alpha to 0

Comment: I wish I could add both the views to the same heirarchy - but that isn't possible - one view belongs to a table view - the other to a container - so they really have no connection or knowledge of each other - The example was only for demonstration purposes (because I was playing around with it) . The goal is for both views to move together - autolayout isn't possible - what I am doing now is manually changing the origin of 'view2' by 'x' pixels - but that is choppy and doesn't look good :(

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's an easy way to omit manually changing the origin. You could consider [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) ([simple explanation here](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)) in order to observe when the origin of the view in scope changes. However, if it's a `UITableViewCell`, it might get you in troubles because of cell reusing.

Answer (score 2):

Set v1 origin 'X' to v2 origin 'X in panGesture.

-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

```
CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

CGRect boundsRect = CGRectMake(15, 40, 285, self.view.frame.size.height-60);

if (CGRectContainsPoint(boundsRect, point))
{
    v1.center = point;
}



v2.frame = CGRectMake(v1.frame.origin.x, v2.frame.origin.y, v2.frame.size.width, v2.frame.size.height);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to solve this could be to add one of the views as a subview to the other or add both as subviews to a new view, which is only used to group the views. Depending on how you intend to use the views this might not be applicable to you though.

If you want to make one view a subview of the other but want the subview to be visible outside the bounds of the superview you can set `clipToBounds` to `NO` on the superview.